# Php installed via bash terminal for windows executes faster than php for windows 10

Tags: php, xampp, config, mamp-pro

The bash terminal used was installed using [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10) tutorial. I don't think using a different cli matters for the execution time of php (as there was no difference between git bash and windows cmd) but for the purpose of making a clear distinction, I refer to it as "executed from bash" (refering to Ubuntu bash terminal), or "executed from git bash" (refering to the git bash terminal for Windows 10).

I have executed the script below a bunch of ways:

1: two seperate windows computers with a MAMP (Pro) and XAMPP stack, which had similar outcomes averaging at about **5.9 seconds**.

2: Executed it with php for windows 10 without a LAMP or XAMPP stack, averaging at about **5.1 seconds**.

3: However, when I execute this code via a Bash terminal (PHP 7.1.26-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)) the avg execution time is around **2.9 seconds**.

```
<?php    
$j=0;
$startTime = microtime(1);

for($i = 0; $i < 199999999; $i++ ){
        $j+=4;
    }

$time = microtime(1) - $startTime;
exit(var_dump($time));
```

**What I have done so far**

Tried running it with -n parameter (which disables the php.ini) from cli so any extensions that could be slowing the proces down would be disabled, but this made no difference:

```
php test.php -n
```

Tried running it as webserver to see if it would make a difference, and this caused the server started from BASH terminal to be **300ms** faster than executed in cli, so **2.6 seconds**. However, it did not matter for the command executed from git bash:

```
php -S localhost:8080 -n
```

Measured differences between real, user and system time, which has quite a big difference in outcome, averaged 10 times on git bash and bash:

**Bash**
real:  0m2.993s
 
user:  0m2.938s
sys:   0m0.063s

**Git bash**
real:  0m5.923s
 
user:  0m0.015s
sys:   0m0.030s

```
time php test.php -n
```

I have no clue where to look further, as it's just the php execution time i am concerned about, for now. Hope someone can help :).

Comment: It's probably some overhead in the windows version of PHP - emulation or somesuch in the stack. Unless a PHP or Windows dev reads this I don't know if you'll get a definitive answer. Why are you concerned about this? You wouldn't host a live application in Windows 10, so it won't affect real world performance.

Comment: Sorry for the slow respond, was hoping on some answers still.
I am concerned about this, because i have a live server that executes this even slower (apache running on centOS), so i hoped for a quickfix based on those minor details. Figured the cause of difference in execution time could be similar to the difference between my bash (ubuntu)- and windows installation.
I am now going to use some profiling tools, hope this will help me allocate my problem.

thanks for taking the time to respond!